# Unable to publish Xamarin App to iPhone. It will not compile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Xamarin Forms v4.3.0.947036  VS 2019

I made a dummy App (Master/Detail Xamarin template) and published it to an iPhone connected to a MAC on my network.  Runs fine.

I have another App (my main App) that functions fine on both Android/iOS emulators and Android Phone.

However, when I try and publish it to the iPhone (iOS 12.4) (same setup as with the Dummy App) I get the following error when I compile:

```
Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/<Initialize>d__22::MoveNext()' in 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

This is the full error in the output window:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): error MT2101: Can't resolve the reference 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Log::Warning(System.String,System.String)', referenced from the method 'System.Void Xamarin.Forms.Pages.BaseDataSource/<Initialize>d__22::MoveNext()' in 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what could possibly be causing the error?

Comment: It would seem as though "Xamarin.Forms.Log" does not exist.  Not sure why this error is only showing up when I campile for a physical iPhone?

Comment: You are really using v1.3 of Xamarin Forms?  That is ~5 years old.

Comment: Aggghh that was a typo, it is v 4.3.0.947036, I'll update the question.  Thanks.

Comment: The only "Pre-Release" software I am using is Xamarin.Forms.Theme.* (1.0.0.43-pre1)

Comment: I would guess you haven't set up provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the pre-release 'themes'. I removed all references to them from any Projects and the error disappeared.

Reference: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140586